# @QueryParam requirements regex not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, query-string

I have a simple API end point set up as follows:

```
/**
 *
 * @QueryParam(name="originLat", requirements="\d+", strict=true, nullable=false)
 * @QueryParam(name="originLng", strict=true, nullable=false)
 * @QueryParam(name="departureTime", requirements="/\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d/", strict=true, nullable=false)
 *
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 */
public function getWalkingJourney(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    $dTime = $paramFetcher->get('departureTime');
    $oLat = $paramFetcher->get('originLat');
    $oLng = $paramFetcher->get('originLng'),
}
```

The [QueryParam][1] for originLat works fine if I pass a simple number, but the more complex departureTime regex always fails with the following message:

```
Parameter "departureTime" of value "2016-09-13 14:47:36" violated a constraint "Parameter 'departureTime' value, does not match requirements '/\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d/'"
```

Which seems counter intuitive, as this is the correct regex.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The `QueryParam` regex can be specified as a string. No need for enclosing in `/`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the [PCRE delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in the `requirements`, which is likely messing up your regex.

Try as `* @QueryParam(name="departureTime", requirements="\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d", strict=true, nullable=false)`

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists: Parameter "departureTime" of value "2016-09-13 15:05:01" violated a constraint "Parameter 'departureTime' value, does not match requirements '\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d'"

Comment: Well, the regex validates the sample input you provide. The problem likely resides in the input not being what you think it is. Use `var_dump()` on the input to inspect it further. There's probably some whitespace there you aren't noticing because you're probably looking at it in your browser or there's some non-printable character you can't see in a console. `var_dump()` will give you string length so this will become more obvious.

Comment: Im doing TDD so Im controlling exactly what is going through. Im also using xdebug so I can see the variable is as expected in the controller. It seems to be an issue with the single space for some reason.

Comment: Could be an issue the way that Symfony component escapes things in your regex, [but the regex itself and the input provided definitely validate as far as PHP is concerned](https://3v4l.org/skTEd).

Answer (score -1):

The problem here was a space issue. The annotations do not handle spaces well, so when the space in the regex was replaced with a \s, everything works fine.

**Does not work**

```
 * @QueryParam(name="departureTime", requirements="\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d", strict=true, nullable=false)     *
```

**Works**

```
 * @QueryParam(name="departureTime", requirements="\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d\s[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d", strict=true, nullable=false)     *
```

Comment: Sounds like a serious screw up on Symfony's part then. Parsing the docblock is trivial. It's built in to PHP. But not knowing how to properly handle parsing quoted strings inside the annotation... that's **Symfony fails at programming 101** to be honest.

Comment: Agreed. I'd followed the code through to their validation library where it manipulates the regex, appending and prepending characters. Im not entirely sure what its doing there tbh, Im no regex expert, but its definitely not staying pure until the point of validation.

Comment: Report a bug against doctrine/annotations, if it is detected as a bug in that implementation. Writing a test case seems to be trivial, see https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/tree/f9cf50745a45cae4a55f35e7691d124c4d887e45/tests/Doctrine/Tests/Common/Annotations/Fixtures

Comment: Raised the bug.